# Is this the proper way to test if an enum is a specific value?

Tags: python, enums

Is using `is` the best way of testing enum values?

```
from enum import Enum

class BoardState(Enum):
    empty = 0
    occupied = 1

    def __str__(self):
      if self is BoardState.empty:
        return '-'
      else:
        return 'X'

state = BoardState.empty        
print(state) # prints '-'
```

Comment: See [enum comparisons](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#comparisons).

Comment: I would consider overriding `__new__` to attach the desired string to each object *once*; then `__str__` simply needs to return the correct attribute instead of checking the identity of the object explicitly.

Comment: And I'd use str Enum and just assign `empty = '-'; occupied = 'X'`..

Comment: @chepner Thank you! Would using `__new__` be preferable to simply assigning each enum element the string value directly, e.g. `empty = '-'`?

Comment: I think it depends on how you plan to use `BoardState`. Maybe 0/1 values are useful more often, maybe the string values are, or maybe there should be two separate enumerate types, one `int`-valued the other `str`-valued.

Comment: (For example, you might want to maintain a clean separation between values representing the *state* of the board from values representing the *presentation* of the board.)

Comment: @chepner Again, thank you. I've been a developer for over 20 years (C/C++) and started looking at Python for the first time recently. Where is my static type safety? ;-) (and yes, I am aware of the `typing` module) Just trying to ensure I do things the pythonic way.

Comment: I've heard it said (mainly from Haskell/Rust-type people) that people who don't like static type systems really just don't like the static type systems used by C/C++/Java :)